# $.ajax displays "�" instead of accents, like "é" or "ã"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to be able to display the letter "é", using $.ajax and a JSON file, but the closest that I get was an alert window saying "�", basically anything will help, just no PHP guys, and yes I have the `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Anyways, here's the JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "alejandra.json",
    contentType: "charset=utf-8; application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var x = data[0].texto;
        alert(x);
    }
});
});
```

And here's the JSON file:

```
[
{
"texto":"é"
}
]
```

PS: This is all running locally in my PC.

Comment: Are you sure that the server is sending it in `utf-8`?

Comment: and meta charset tag is set to utf-8?

Comment: @EvanKnowles I mean, this is all running locally, so I'm not 100% sure, but why it wouldn't be?

Comment: @charlietfl In the HTML yes

Comment: right click on your file and open it with notepad, click on File -> Save as, change encoding to `UTF-8` if it's not

Comment: @LuthandoLoot I can't even believe that it worked, thank you so much sir!

Comment: You're welcome, I'll make this an answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This Solved the OP's Question**

Right click on your file and open it with notepad, click on `File` -> `Save as`, change encoding to `UTF-8` if it's not

Answer (score 1):

in a very quick test I just performed:

content type `charset=utf-8;application/json` (incorrect) is not the same as content type `application/json;charset=utf-8` (correct)

---

the above doesn't make any difference actually, my testing was on what content type the server sent (which does make a difference in some cases)

make sure the .json file is saved UTF-8 encoded - I originally saved it as ansi and it didn't work, but saved in UTF-8 works fine

Answer (score 0):

May be you need `.toLocaleLowerCase()` method:

```
success: function(data) {
    var x = data[0].texto.toLocaleLowerCase();
    alert(x);
}
```

> ### Description
>
> The ***toLocaleLowerCase()*** method returns the value of the string converted to lower case according to any locale-specific case mappings. toLocaleLowerCase() does not affect the value of the string itself. In most cases, this will produce the same result as toLowerCase(), but *for some locales, such as Turkish, whose case mappings do not follow the default case mappings in Unicode*, there may be a different result.